# Cancel repeating alarm between two dates

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to have a feature in which the user can set repeating alarms. Alarm will repeat it self weekly. But the user can also set the alarm off between two dates inputted by them... I am having difficulty in proceeding with it. kindly provide me a way out.

Comment: What have you done so far? Please post code of your current implementation. If it's AlarmManager, you may find the docs https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html to be helpful.

Comment: create a class that extends BroadcastReceiver. in onRecieve method use Calendar class, Joda library,  notify user whenever the day comes.